# mock, stub, fake para pruebas unitarias?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, asp.net-mvc-5

Inicie un nuevo proyecto con varios servicios uno de ellos es un servicio para usuarios, este servicio requiere de un repositorio, ahora para todos los servicios quiero agregar pruebas unitarias, para este primer servicio agregue los metodos basicos e hice una prueba unitaria.

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void UsuarioServicio_Registrar_NuevoUsuario()
        {
            //arrange
            Usuario nuevoUsuario = new Usuario { Nombre = "fulanito", Telefono = "555-5464" };

            var servicio = new UsuarioServicio(new UsuarioRepositorioMock());

            //act
            var idNuevoUsuario = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(nuevoUsuario);

            //assert

            Assert.IsTrue(idNuevoUsuario > 0);
        }
```

para esta prueba unitaria realice un mock del repositorio

```
  public class UsuarioRepositorioMock : IUsuarioRepositorio
        {
            public int CrearUsuario(Usuario usuario)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            public Usuario ActualizarUsuario(Usuario usuario)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public bool BorrarUsuario(int UsuarioId)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public Usuario ObtenerUsuario(Usuario usuario)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

bueno en sentido escricto es un stub,

lo que no quiero es implementar los siguientes metodos en este mock repositorio
porque a medida que agregue metodos este mock sera mas grande y mas complejo.

Que es lo mas recomendable sustituirlo por un Mock Framework o un Fake framework?
gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que planteas se utiliza `Moq`

[Moq.Net. Introducción, cómo utilizarlo y ejemplos](https://blogs.encamina.com/piensa-en-software-desarrolla-en-colores/moq-net-introduccion-utilizarlo-ejemplos/)

La idea es que definas desde fuera el comportamiento de la entidad que mockeas

```
[TestMethod]
public void UsuarioServicio_Registrar_NuevoUsuario()
{
    //arrange
    Usuario nuevoUsuario = new Usuario { Nombre = "fulanito", Telefono = "555-5464" };

    var usuarioRepo = new Mock<IUsuarioRepositorio>();
    usuarioRepo.Setup(m => m.CrearUsuario(It.IsAny<Usuario>())).Returns(1);

    var servicio = new UsuarioServicio(usuarioRepo.Object);

    //act
    var idNuevoUsuario = servicio.RegistrarUsuario(nuevoUsuario);

    //assert

    Assert.IsTrue(idNuevoUsuario > 0);
}
```

Agregas la referencia usando nuget

[Moq nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/)

con solo la interfaz alcanza para definir el comportamiento que puedes ir variando en los diferentes test